# Scale Matrix to a new range

Tags: matlab, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MATLAB: how to normalize/denormalize a vector to range [-1;1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684622/matlab-how-to-normalize-denormalize-a-vector-to-range-11)
>   [matlab rescale matrix data to -1 to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641232/matlab-rescale-matrix-data-to-1-to-1)

Consider a 100x200 matrix `A`, is there a `builtin` function (or set of `builtin` functions) that will set the range of `A` to an arbitrary scale?

Comment: This question is already answered here.

[<a>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab</a>][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. What do you mean by `builtin`? Do you want a single `builtin` function or can you use series of `builtin` functions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: that scales only to -1...1. I don't see where I could change it to apply another range

Comment: @user1958604: that question hasn't nothing to do with mine!

Comment: @slayton: a series of builtin is good too

Comment: @woodchips: that questions can't be adapted to a custom range and it refers only to vectors

Comment: Sure it is. If you can scale a matrix to one range, you can scale it to any range you wish. All it takes is addition/subtraction and multiplication/division, nothing more than it took for the other operation.

Comment: Why not create your own function? Do you need a builtin function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this qualify?

```
R = [.5 .9];
dR = diff( R );

A =  A - min( A(:)); % set range of A between [0, inf)
A =  A ./ max( A(:)) ; % set range of A between [0, 1]
A =  A .* dR ; % set range of A between [0, dRange]
A =  A + R(1); % shift range of A to R
```

Comment: +1 I tought it was easier...

Comment: I have tested it, and the matrix A has totally wrong values :(

Comment: @link, yea I just noticed that, fixed the bug :)

Comment: there is an error on your last line, also i don't understand why you use function like minus instead of the simple operator

Comment: Also `rtimes` doesn't seem to be a function, could you run your code before posting please?

Comment: with rtimes do you mean `.*` ?

Comment: I understand why you used function instead of sign, because I said builtin... LOL I believe you misunderstood me :D... I meant with builtin if there was a function like matrixScale builtin in Matlab... But you could have used simply used the math operator. I have edited the answer