# Matrix dimensions must agree?

Tags: math, matlab

Hi I keep getting the error:

```
    >> maxM = max(M);
    >> minM = min(M);
    >> Mnormalize = ((M-minM)./(maxM-minM) - 0.5 ) *2;
    ??? Error using ==> minus
    Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

M file looks like this
[image]

Comment: What's the dimensions of `M`?

Comment: updated forgot to add the image dimensions is 49K by 42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs if `M` is a two dimensional matrix.

If this is the case, then `maxM` and `minM` will actually be *rows* of `M`, and it fails due to the fact that you can't take for instance `[1 2; 3 4] - [1 2]`.

If you want the minimum / maximum of the whole matrix, you probably want to do

```
maxM = max(M(:))
minM = min(M(:))
```

...and as PengOne said, `/` (instead of `./`) should do just fine in this case.

**Related question:**

- [How to normalize / denormalize a vector to range [-1;1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684622/matlab-how-to-normalize-denormalize-a-vector-to-range-11)